# Pass coordinates via ajax to php server-side, and retrieve to javascript after they were processed

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to transfer some coordinates to php (server-side) from javascript (client-side) via Ajax, and after processing (filter, etc) I want to retrieve the result to javascript, for use. The pass to php working, but I don't know how get and use the processed result from php. Any help is highly appreciated.

The php part script is:

```
$dbconn = pg_connect ("host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres password=xxxxxxx dbname=yyyyyyyy")  or die('can not connect!'.pg_last_error());


//The nearest point of Start point
$ss='';
if (isset($_POST['kuldes_st'])){

    $kuldes=$_POST['kuldes_st'];
    $latk=$_POST['lat_st'];
    $lngk=$_POST['lng_st'];
    $query = "SELECT ST_X(the_geom), ST_Y(the_geom) FROM tbl_mypoints ORDER BY ST_Distance(the_geom, ST_GeomFromText('POINT($latk $lngk)', 4326)) LIMIT 1";
    //$result = pg_query($query) or die('The query failed: ' . pg_last_error()); 
    $result = pg_query($dbconn,$query);
    if (!$result) {
        die('The query failed: ' . pg_last_error()); 
    }
    else {
        while ($line =pg_fetch_row($result))
        { 
            $latitude=$line[0];
            $longitude =$line[1]; 
            $ss .= "L.latLng(".$latitude.", ".$longitude.")"; 
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($ss);
}
```

Javascript code:

```
    map.on('click', function(e) {
        var container = L.DomUtil.create('div'),
            startBtn = createButton('Start from this location', container),
            destBtn = createButton('Go to this location', container);
            nearestBtn = createButton('Find and go to nearest parking', container);

        //Start 
        L.DomEvent.on(startBtn, 'click', function() {
            control.spliceWaypoints(0, 1, e.latlng);
            var lats=e.latlng.lat;
            var lngs=e.latlng.lng;

            $.ajax({
                url : 'index.php',
                type : 'POST',
                async : true,
                data : { 'kuldes_st':1,
                         'lat_st': lats,
                         'lng_st': lngs
                },
                success: function(data,response) {
                     if (response == 'success') {
                          alert("Post working fine");
                          alert(response);
                          console.log(data);
                          } else {
                           alert("Post don't working");
                           console.log(data);
                     }
                }
            });
            map.closePopup();
        });
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of the data returned from the Ajax call?  That is, what does `console.log(data)` look like?

Comment: L.latLng(46.5481770014588, 24.5315265655518)<html>

<head>

    <title>Fogyatekos parkolok honlapja</title>

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />

    
.....

Comment: L.latLng(46.5481770014588, 24.5315265655518) is the correct response, but how can extract and use?

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is how to use return value.
in index.php file , you can return value without html tags. for example, if you wants to return array of number, just use code like this:

```
echo implode($array,",");
```

the data that return by ajax function is some things like this:

```
1,2,4,2
```

you can split this string to a javascript array with code like this:

```
var result = data.split(",");
```

after it, you can use the array result every where you want in jquery code.

Answer (score 0):

My PHP is a bit rusty but I think the issue is that you are returning a string that is not JSON but trying to pack it up like JSON.

I think you want something more like

```
$ss = array();

while ($line =pg_fetch_row($result))
{   
    $latlng = array();
    $latlng["lat"] = $line[0];
    $latlng["lng"] = $line[1]; 
    array_push($ss,$latlng);
}

echo json_encode($ss)
```

Forgive my PHP if it's wrong, but hopefullly from this you get the idea.  At this point, the thing the server will return should look like real JSON like (

```
[
 {"lat":46.5,"lng":24.5},
 {"lat":46.5,"lng":24.5},
 ...
]
```

Then in the javascript, you can just deal with it like an array.

```
var latitudeOfTheFirstEntry = data[0].lat;
var longitudeOfTheSecondEntry = data[1].lng;
```

Do you know what `L.latLng` is supposed to be providing. This solution I've outlined is not using that and if that is needed, there maybe more work to figure out where that is supposed to happen.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much! This helps me.